# How to select multiple variables in R starting with common name?

Tags: r, variables

As in SAS we can start multiple varibles using colon(:) option with start name. I wanted to do the same in R for modeling purpose.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
dat <-  structure(list(ColA = c(9L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 8L), ColB = c(17L, 15L, 
19L, 13L, 12L), C = c(30L, 26L, 23L, 29L, 25L)), .Names = c("ColA", 
"ColB", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5"))
```

Suppose if `Col` is the common name of the variables that needs to be selected

```
dat[grep("Col", colnames(dat))]
```